# Robot Monitor gives an error, how to set imu0_pose_covariance?

Tags: navigation, gmapping, ekf-localization, robot-localization, yaw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Robot Monitor says:

> **imu0_pose_covariance:** The covariance at position (35), which
> corresponds to YAW variance, was zero.
> This will be replaced with a small
> value to maintain filter stability,
> but should be corrected at the message
> origin node.

I've set this under ekf_localization tag in my controls.yaml file;

```
     ...
     ekf_localization:
       ...
       imu0_pose_covariance: [1e-5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                              0.0, 1e-5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                              0.0, 0.0, 1e-5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-5, 0.0, 0.0,
                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-5, 0.0,
                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-5]
       ...
```

But still no effect. How can I set this? Or How can I correct this problem?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223517/robot-monitor-gives-an-error,-how-to-set-imu0_pose_covariance?/) by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2016-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`imu0_pose_covariance` is not a [setting](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) for `ekf_localization_node`.  The covariances for measurements, including IMU data, come from the [sensor_msgs/Imu message](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html) itself. Check your IMU driver.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1